# метод write_database возвращает None а не id

Tags: mysql, python

У меня есть функция, которая из БД берет определенную строку и возвращает id, но функция возвращает не id, как задумывалось, а None. В чем проблема?

**Data Base**

```
class DataBase:
    def __init__(self, user, password, db):
        self.user = user
        self.password = password
        self.db = db
        try:
            conn = self.get_conn()
            # if conn.is_connected():
            #     print('Подключение прошло успешно.')
        except Error as e:
            print(e)

    def get_conn(self):
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=self.user,
                                       password=self.password,
                                       db=self.db)
        return conn

    def get_subcategory_id(self, title):
        sql = "SELECT id FROM buy.subcategory WHERE title = '{0}';".format(title)
        conn = self.get_conn()
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute(sql)
        id = c.fetchall()

        return (id)
```

**Code python**

```
class Tesco:
    def write_database(self, data):
        data_base = db.DataBase('root', '123456', 'buy')
        data_base.get_subcategory_id(data['title'])

    def get_products(self, html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        name_sub_category = soup.find('span', class_='plp--breadcrumbs--last-crumb').text

         data = {
             'title': name_sub_category
         }

        print(self.write_database(data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return отсутствует? Надо что-то вроде:

```
def write_database(self, data):
    data_base = db.DataBase('root', '123456', 'buy')
    return data_base.get_subcategory_id(data['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй такую конструкцию

```
cursor.execute(sql, ())
for field in cursor:
    print("found: ", fields)
```

Должно сработать, у меня сработало.

Answer (score 0):

У вас в конструкции `id = c.fetchall()` не возвращается ни одной записи, а чтобы взять первую надо использовать `id[0]`, а чтобы взять `id` из этой записи, то скорее всего `id[0][0]`